# How can i encode a string to UTF-8 to a pre existing byte array?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, encoding, utf-8

I have a simple bit of code that converts a C# string by encoding it to UTF-8 then creating a byte array from it. But i am wondering how can i encode to UTF-8 using a byte array i have already made at a starting index?

So this is how i am currently encoding and getting the resulting byte array:

```
byte[] result = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myString);
```

But I have a byte array premade that i would prefer to write to at a specific index if that makes sense. Is there any built in method to do this, if not how would i go about it ?

Comment: Use the other overload of GetBytes...

Comment: Do you need bytes again once you encode or you need string?

Comment: @mikez ah damn i had no idea that overload existed. My bad. Thanks for that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[GetBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c20ss51h(v=vs.110).aspx) has another overload that writes to existing array:

```
  byte[] bytes = new byte[1000]; // sample, make sure it has enough space
  var specificIndex = 0;
  var actualByteCount = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
     myString, 0, myString.Length, bytes, specificIndex);
```

Don't forget to handle result to know how many bytes in the array actually represent string (`actualByteCount`)

Note you may need to use `GetByteCount` to get correct array size or adjust number of characters to convert to fit into your buffer.

Answer (score -1):

First you will need to convert your bytes into Base64String then convert that into bytes. Likes this:

```
byte[] random = new byte[] { 0x00C9, 0x00C9, 0x00C9 };

byte[] encodedBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Convert.ToBase64String(random));
```